# Setting up EXT.NET to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ext.net

How can I setup EXT.NET to VS 2008?

I'm new to EXT.NET and I understand that for it to work with VS you must have at least VS2010. But because of this link https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2005-&-2008

I got an idea that it's possible. However the tutorial is quite confusing for me. If you can provide me a more simpler instruction or alternative that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ext.NET .zip download package (http://ext.net/download/) includes .NET 3.5 compiled .dlls. You should be able to add those as a Reference in your VS2008 project.

The .NET 3.5 compiles .dlls are available in the `lib > NET35` folder of the .zip package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean I just need to add those as a reference then it's done?

Comment: It would be best to review the README.txt (http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/README/) and Sample Web.config (http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/Sample_Web.config/). After adding the References to the .dll's, the Web.config needs to be updated with some information. The bits required are outlined in the two documents above. Hope this helps.